# Philippine passport w/ U.S. Permanent Resident Card (GreenCard) - need Visa to travel to Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, cruising, residency, filipino-citizens

Thinking of going on cruise with stops in Canada.
I have Philippine passport w/ U.S. Permanent Resident Card (GreenCard).
Do i need to get a canadian Visa?

Info on Canada website is a little confusing.

Comment: You can double check your specific situation with this tool: http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/getting-started.asp

Comment: The online tool did give a good summary, not too many questions, and it did give a personal checklist at the end. Turns out you don't need a visa if you have a philippine passport and a US green card.